# What is Conditional Random Field actually are?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, crf

I new in machine learning, especially in **Conditional Random Fields(CRF)**

I have read several articles and papers and in there is always associated with HMM and sequences classification. I don't really understand mathematics, especially in the annoying formula.So I can't understand the process

> Where i need to start ?

I want to make an information extraction application using CRF Named Entity Recognition(NER)

I got some tutorial for that : https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn_crfsuite.html#training-data

**But** i dont know the proses each step, like training proses,evaluation, and testing

and 1 more things make me confused :

```
crf = sklearn_crfsuite.CRF(
    algorithm='lbfgs',
    c1=0.1,
    c2=0.1,
    max_iterations=20,
    all_possible_transitions=False,
)
```

**What is algortihm lbfgs ???**

is the CRF not an algorithm?? why need lbfgs ?

> So please tell me what is CRF are ? and please explain it

Answer (score 0):

CRF is a probabilistic graphical model used mostly for sequence labeling tasks.
To get an understanding and differences between HMM,CRF you may want to check this 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58221/intuitive-difference-between-hidden-markov-models-and-conditional-random-fields

For an in depth understanding of CRF, please go through https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/papers/crf-tutorial.pdf

If your data has some structure and patterns to it CRF would be a good algorithm to start with. You can get some annotated data here: 
https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2003/ner/

LBFGS is for optimization.

Here is a quick tutorial to build an NER system using CRF.
https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Hope that helps!